# Desativar o Scroll da página em um momento específico

Tags: javascript, html, css

Eu fiz uma espécie de carrossel com CSS e um pouco de JavaScript com algumas imagens e a medida em que eu uso o scroll do mouse em cima da imagens as imagens vão passando para o lado, o problema é que a página também desce a medida que eu uso o scroll para passar as imagens. Sou iniciante na programação e não tenho ideia de **como desativar o scroll da página enquanto o mouse estiver encima das imagens**.

O código das imagens HTML:

```
<div id="galeria">
    <div id="itens">
        <div class="item">
            <img src="imagens/Chrysanthemum.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="imagens/Desert.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="imagens/Tulips.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="imagens/Koala.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="imagens/Penguins.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

O código CSS:

```
#galeria{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#itens{
    display: flex;
    overflow-x: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
}

.item{
    flex: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
    scroll-snap-align: start;
    pointer-events: none;
}

img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 98%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

O código do JavaScript:

```
document.querySelector("#itens").addEventListener("wheel", event => {

            if(event.deltaY > 0){
                event.target.scrollBy(300, 0)
            }else{
                event.target.scrollBy(-300, 0)
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente o seguinte:

```
document.querySelectorAll("#itens img").forEach(img => {
  img.addEventListener('mouseenter', ()=> document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden')
  img.addEventListener('mouseleave', ()=> document.body.style.overflow = null)
})
```

Essa é uma solução simples, mas direta para a sua questão.

Primeiro, se você quer remover o scroll só para as imagens, deve seleciona-las, por isso adicionei o `img` no `querySelectorAll`.

"`overflow: hidden`" é uma das formas mais simples de remover scroll e isso funciona no `body`.

Para retornar ao normal, basta anular a definição de `overflow`. (forma simples)

E para isso funcionar legal, os eventos adequados são `mouseenter` e `mouseleave`.

Comment: Ok, funcionou, obrigado